# People keep crashing when playing or joining my room, how can I prevent that from happening?

Tags: rec-room

I have a room that is pretty full of props, circuits, gadgets, and makerpen shapes, but when people try to join, they either crash to their dorm room, or get laden with excessive lag that eventually crashes them shortly after loading in.

The platforms that are most affected seem to be PSVR and Quest players. They may have to attempt several times to join the room before actually being able to join.

So far I've reduced the ink usage in the room down to 70% by removing some extra details and circuits but they're still encountering problems loading in and playing the game.

What are some things I can do to make the room easier to load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known bug right now that is causing lower-end hardware to have issues with loading really high detailed rooms with people already in them.  I believe the team has identified what it is and is working on a solution.

In the mean time, encourage quest and PSVR players to join the room privately.  Its not ideal, but typically will work.  My theory is there is something to do with time-out when loading a room.  You have to load all of the detail of a room, then start getting data about every player's movement in the room.  And getting that double-hit of data might be too much for PSVR or Quest, and it either times out and kicks you back to dorm, or crashes.